# How to get the value of a Vuetify Select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify select (v-select):

```
 <v-select prepend-icon="local_shipping" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Es necesario asignarl el T.A.R.']" required label="T.A.R." v-model="editedItem.tarID" :items="tars" item-text="nombre" item-value="id"></v-select>
```

What i want to do is get the value of the id in edit mode, that is, in this way:

[image]

I have been following the official documentation of vuetify to edit an item of a table in a modal dialog.

Just as the inputs have assigned text, I would also like the select to have its assigned data.

Here is what i have:
The edit button:

```
<v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(props.item)">
          <v-icon color="info">mode_edit</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
```

The editedItem and the defaultItem, just like the official documentation:

```
editedItem: {
    entidadID: "",
    numeroEstacion: "",
    tarID: "",
    clave: "",
    id:""
  },
  defaultItem: {
    entidadID: "",
    numeroEstacion: "",
    tarID: "",
    clave: "",
    id: ""
  },
```

The way in which i populate the v-select in data:

```
 tars: [
    {
      id: "",
      nombre: ""
    }
  ],
```

I populate my tables like this:

```
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    hide-actions
    class="slideInDown"
    :search="search"
    :id="items.id"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.grupo }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.numeroEstacion}}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.clave }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.nombre }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.id}}</td>
      <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
          <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="info">mode_edit</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon class="mx-o" @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="red">delete_sweep</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
      </td>
    </template>
    <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
      Tu búsqueda para "{{search}}" no arrojó resultados.
    </v-alert>
  </v-data-table>
```

And the editItem button:

```
 editItem(item) {
  this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item);      
  this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
  this.dialog = true;
},
```

The editedIndex equals -1 in data return. So when i touch New Item button editedIndex = -1, when i touch The edit button, editedIndex != -1, like the documentation

The link of the official documentation:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables

Here is my PUT method:

```
      if(this.editedIndex > -1){
      axios({
          headers:{
              "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')
          },
          method: "put",
          url: "http://localhost:58209/api/PutEstacion",
          data:{
                NumeroEstacion: this.editedItem.numeroEstacion,
                Clave: this.editedItem.clave,
                **TarID: this.editedItem.tarID**,
                ID: this.editedItem.id,
          }

      }).then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.snackbar = true;
          this.textSnackbar = "La información ha sido actualizada correctamente";
          this.dialog = false
      }).catch(error =>{
          console.log(error.response);
          this.snackbar = true;
          this.textSnackbar = "Lo sentimos ha ocurrido un problema actualizando la informacíón";
          this.dialog = false
      });
  }
```

This line: `TarID: this.editedItem.tarID` has no value. So i can't put in my WebApi. And finally my WbApi:

```
 var ID = _context.Estacion.Where(x => x.ID == putEstacionDTO.ID).Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault();
  var NumeroEstacion = putEstacionDTO.NumeroEstacion;
  var Clave = putEstacionDTO.Clave;
  var TarID = putEstacionDTO.TarID;

  var putEstacion = _context.LoadStoredProc("PutEstaciones")
    .WithSqlParam("p0", NumeroEstacion)
    .WithSqlParam("p1", Clave)
    .WithSqlParam("p2", TarID)
    .WithSqlParam("p3", ID)
    .ExecuteStoredProc<PutEstacionDTO>();
  return Ok();
```

When i debugging only the 'select' = 0 (TarID).

**EDIT, Add the :items="items" of datatable**
Data:

```
      items: [
              {
      id: "",
      grupo: "",
      numeroEstacion: "",
      clave: "",
      nombre: "",
    }
  ],
```

Method to set the items:

```
axios
      .get("http://localhost:58209/api/GetEstaciones", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.items = response.data;
        this.snackbar = true;
        this.textSnackbar = "Se han cargado correctamente las estaciones";
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
        this.snackbar = true;
        this.textSnackbar =
          "Lo sentimos, no pudimos cargar la información de los tanques";
      });
```

Comment: @Ohgodwhy here: `v-model="editedItem.tarID"`

Comment: Well i post all of my code. According to official documentation. When i touch the Edit button, the Object.assign fill the inputs, with the indexOf of the table. And then the modal appears. Finnaly when i touch Save button, call the axios.put method. The code is in the post :)

Comment: Can you post out the sample data for `:items="items"`?

Comment: @Sphinx Sure :)

Comment: @Sphinx i updated the post to add the code

Comment: so it doesn't have keys=tarId when bind :item="items". change to `this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item, {'tar':index})` then try again.

Comment: Ok, well, now i can Put if i choose manually that 'Select', the API catch the value with this line: `TarID: this.editedItem.tarID,`. But in the modal is not assigned

Comment: what does mean `the modal is not assigned`?

Comment: @Sphinx, like the image, the v-select of the T.A.R. is not populated like the others inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169615/discussion-between-sphinx-and-isaias-orozco-toledo).

Comment: @Sphinx i found the solution, i never get the ID of the TAR table, only the name. and when i get the ID and use it in props of the table, now the v-select is binded. Thank you so much

Comment: That is to say, i update my sql query an now i add the id of my TAR table in the select statement